# Redirect to custom tool url in a laravel nova application

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-nova

- Laravel Version: 7
- Nova Version: 3
- PHP Version: 7.4
- Database Driver & Version:
- Operating System and Version: MacOS
- Browser type and version: Chrome
- Reproduction Repository: https://github.com/###/###

#### Description:

I am trying to redirect a user after checking for a condition in a middleware, I have tried to use

```
return redirect('/admin/paddle-subscription');
```

But it does not work, it just redirects the page and shows it right in the browser url but show a 404 error in the screen, it looks  that as nova uses vue.js it is creating some kind of errors.

I have been reading some post in laracast   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/nova/nova-resource-route-redirect and it is clearer to me that it requires a special way to redirect.

I have tried

```
     return redirect()->action('\Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\RouterController@show', ['resource' => '/admin/paddle-subscription']);
```

And it does not work, how I am supposed to redirect properly?

Thanks

#### Detailed steps to reproduce the issue on a fresh Nova installation:

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating the route in the backend first so that Laravel knows the page exists. Use Nova's `RouterController@show` action for the route like in your Laracast example and make sure to apply all the Nova middleware to it.

In `app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php` add a custom route to your `routes()` method:

```
protected function routes()
{
    Nova::routes()
        ->withAuthenticationRoutes()
        ->withPasswordResetRoutes()
        ->register();

    Route::domain(config('nova.domain', null))
        ->middleware(['web'])
        ->as('nova.')
        ->prefix(Nova::path())
        ->group(function () {
            Route::get('/admin/paddle-subscription', [\Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\RouterController::class, 'show'])
                ->middleware(config('nova.middleware', []));
        });
}
```

In your middleware you can now redirect to that route and the page will render properly:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($foo === $bar) {
        return new \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse('/admin/paddle-subscription');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

add in your nova action

```php
public function handleRequest(\Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\ActionRequest $request)
{
    parent::handleRequest($request);

    return Action::redirect('/admin/paddle-subscription');
}
```